# Should I diversify? If so, into what?

Tags: investing, canada, diversification

I am 29 years old. I worked very hard at a well-paying (but not exciting) job and spent my vacation time buying and renovating properties. Currently, I have 4 condos with an approximate equity of 445,000. All my units have been completely renovated and that number is just using what other units have sold for recently. A savings account around the 70,000 mark and no debt other than mortgages. One of the properties I live in but also rent a room; the other 3 are rented out for positive cash flow. The real estate market here has been going pretty insane for a while and I expect it to cool off in the next 2 years (still go up slowly but reach a price cap for awhile after 2 years). **Should I sell and diversify my holdings?**

I am working towards a Ph.D. in mathematics and, thus, for the next while my income is low and paying taxes on capital gains may make sense. I have a scholarship at my university that covers my mortgage and living expenses so the purpose of the money is just for investing. I also have a 50k line of credit so I don't really need to hold any funds aside if an emergency comes up I can cover it if I'm slow to liquidate or it's a bad time.

I live in Canada and have run my own investment account before on the stock market trading shares and options and made a lot of money doing it but don't really want to spend that level of time while in school.

I would like to be semi-retired by 50 though given I really like what I am doing now I guess that's not really a big deal.

Comment: Do you enjoy being a landlord? If you sold one or more units would you need the money for anything else or just invest it all elsewhere?  What are your mortgage rates and loan to value ratios?

Comment: I don't need the money for anything else just investing, two of the units are managed by a propetymanagement company as one is rather far away I make about 70-100$ per unit after mortgage is paid strata fees and property management company is paid if relevant. The other unit has a disabled man in and I don't want him bothered so I manage the unit and give him a break on rent so I make about the same off it he's been in there for 5 years and is a good tenant checks come straight to me from the government.

Comment: The rates aren't great on the rentals because there rather small mortgages 100k on the one worth 180k, 82k and 88k on the other two worth about 160k each probally more given the renovations.

Comment: *I also have a 50k line of credit so i dont really need to hold any funds aside if an emergency comes* - If an emergency comes, first thing is your loc gets cancelled!

Comment: I've been with the same lender for over 7 years multiple mortgages credit line credit card and an investment account with more money in it then my credit line I've never missed a payment on anything ever and have credit score around 850 who in the right mind would piss me off to leave to anthor lender?

Comment: How much equity do you have in the rentals? 70-100$ per unit doesn't sound like a lot of return. Are they highly leveraged?

Comment: Two of them are in a very old building that they should just knock down and build new condos the lot is big enough for two massive buildings which why I bought the redid the front of the building to brand new and want to do the other sides so the strata fees are 303 and 305 for the units mortgage and taxes in is 440 and 435 they are rented out for 900 a pieces the other ones probally more money cause the strata only 150 so it probally makes 250 or something in positive cash flow.

Comment: My point is, if you have $100K equity in a unit and it makes $100 per month, that's only a 1.2% return. Either your rent is too low and/or you've got too much going to debt payments.

Comment: @DStanley That's after mortgage payment, you'd have to add in principle payment for your return calculation, and from numbers provided looks like ~80k equity in each. Might still be lean margins.

Comment: About 260 goes to principal so it's not bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately, yes, you should diversify, being solely invested in residential real estate is somewhat risky, a mix of stocks, bonds, and real estate would most likely be safer. The harder questions to answer are how soon should you diversify, and should you sell one or more units in order to diversify?

Since your rates aren't great, it may be worth selling one unit to pay down/off loans on others, that's guaranteed benefit. Be sure to calculate your effective rate after tax benefit from interest deduction to know how much you're actually getting by paying down debt. Similarly, when comparing rental property to other investments make sure to factor in depreciation (capital cost allowance) which provides some benefit.

If you enjoy being a landlord and think you'd like to do that for a while longer or maybe in perpetuity, then don't sell now just to diversify, but rather plan to diversify when you have money to invest again. You seem well-positioned to weather a minor down-turn, so stick with things as they are for now and then max out contributions to tax advantaged retirement accounts when income is flowing again.

Being a landlord over a few paid off properties seems like an ideal semi-retirement to me, but it's not for everyone.